# What status code to return in web api?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, http-status-codes

I am writing a `Web API` application and I have a particular `POST` method which just pushes a message in to a database in server side.

I do not want to send back the `id` of the `newly created entry in the database`.

Just want to send the client that the request is `success`

What is the `HTTP CODE` that should be returned in this case ?

`HTTP 200` OR `HTTP 201` ?

**EDIT:**

Googled about status code

`http 200` means `ok` and `http 201` means `created`.

Here i am creating a resource but dont want to send the id of the newly created resource. 
What should be the return code in this case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) states that a body SHOULD be returned for 201:

> The response SHOULD include an entity containing a list of resource characteristics and location(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate

If you do not want to specify a body you should return "204 No Content".